# lscm annotate not working in Sonar Qube from Jazz

Tags: sonarqube, ibm-jazz

cmd /C call lscm annotate is not finding then last commtied user in Sonar Qube.

I am using Jazz as Scm and Sonar Qube.

When running the Sonar Qube all the issues are not assigned for a project.

Comment: I get the message Skipping untracked file: Annotate command exit code: 1

Comment: The same command runs fine in the Command line

Comment: I am using rtc scm 6.02